# Unity 2D how to make instantiated object fly to some other object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I am trying to make something like a machine gun, and I can not make `Rigidbody.AddForce()` work like I want. I want instantiated bullets to fly exactly to the direction of the player, but it does not always work correctly:

[image: Working Screenshot] [image: Non-working screenshot]

And here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Laser : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;
    public GameObject ammo;
    public int bulletsPerSec = 10;
    public float shootPauseDuration = 3.0f;
    public float force = 5.0f;
    int bullets = 0;
    bool pause = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        TrackPlayer();
    }

    void TrackPlayer()
    {
        float AngleRad = Mathf.Atan2(target.position.y - transform.position.y, 
                                     target.position.x - transform.position.x);
        float AngleDeg = 180 / Mathf.PI * AngleRad;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, AngleDeg);
        Debug.Log(transform.rotation);

        Shoot();
    }

    void Shoot()
    {
        if(bullets < bulletsPerSec)
        {
            bullets++;
            GameObject bullet = Instantiate(ammo, transform.position,
                                            transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(
                              transform.rotation * transform.up * force,
                              ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            Destroy(bullet, 3.0f);
        }
        else if(pause==false)
        {
            pause = true;
            StartCoroutine("ShootPause");
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ShootPause()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(shootPauseDuration);
        bullets = 0;
        pause = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why did you do

```
// Quaternion?    // * Vector3?
transform.rotation * transform.up * force
```

shouldn't it be...

```
transform.eulerAngles.normalized * force
```

other solution which will work

```
(target.position - transform.position).normalized * force
```

Comment: Your first suggestion did not worked (bullets just stayed in one place, not moving), but the second one worked. Thanks for your help :)